# Algebraic replacement

Tags: replacement, algebraic-manipulation

How do I replace an algebraic expression with a symbol? I'm trying to replace repeated terms such as $(a+b)$ with c, for example, so that $x(4a + 4b) + x^2(6a + 6b)$ becomes $x4c + x^26c$ .

Comment: `4 x (a + b) + 6 x^2 (a + b) /. {(a + b) -> c}`

Comment: `Expand[Simplify[fun,a+b==c]]`

Comment: Generally, make the LHS of a rule as simple as possible, e.g., `x (4 a + 4 b) + x^2 (6 a + 6 b) /. a -> c - b // Simplify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun = x (4 a + 4 b) + x^2 (6 a + 6 b);

Collect[fun, {a, b}]/2 /. a | b :> c
```

c*(4*x + 6*x^2)

```
Expand[%]
```

4*c*x + 6*c*x^2

Comment: (+1) I think it is direct if you apply: `Collect[fun, {x}, Factor] /. a + b -> c`

Comment: Thank you, E., that's a better variant :)

Comment: You're welcome, @eldo, it's a pleasure to interact with you and provide feedback! :-)